# No weather data from Yahoo Weather API

Tags: yql, yahoo-api, weather-api, yahoo-weather-api

Yahoo retired its YQL API so, I am switching to use the OAuth1.0 protected weather forecast API,

https://weather-ydn-yql.media.yahoo.com/forecastrss?w=2502265

Got whitelisted my app through email as instructed here, https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/

Sending request to get weather data with the proper Authorization header returns nothing but this, error status: 500

```
<rss xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#" xmlns:yweather="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <yweather:units distance="mi" pressure="in" speed="mph" temperature="F"/>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: If you set `format=json`, there is a little more info about the error: `Unable to identify AppId for request Id`. But passing the AppId does not change anything.

Comment: Hi, Did they reply your email and told you that you're in whitelist? I sent to them few days ago. And no any reply! Seems they need to use `oauth_consumer_key` and other stuff for the request.

Comment: @YuanFu yes, they replied to my email that it got whitelisted, before that, I was getting Invalid OAuth credentials" (401 error) response. This response looks like an internal server error.

Comment: Wondering if you figured it out. In postman I am getting a 500 server error when making a request. setting format to json doesn't give me any details. I just see 500 error.

Comment: I got the email from them and I use [OhhAuth](https://github.com/mw99/OhhAuth) for Swift. Works fine from me. If you use Swift as well. Might help you, Otherwise, you might need to find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very quick support from the Yahoo team. Below is their answer regarding this issue:

> Hi,
>
> Maybe you missed our earlier email but there was some service
>   reliability issues, which should work well now. Please try again and
>   let us know if you have any other problems. You can also read through
>   the code examples on
>   https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/documentation.html for sample
>   OAuth1 call to our API.
>
> PS: if you still encounter problems with Postman, please try curl
>   command instead, which should have more reliable and valid response.
>
> Regards,
>
> Yahoo Weather Team

I can confirm, my app successfully connect to the weather API without any change on my code (no more 500 error)

Answer (score -2):

They are retiring their weather API. Did you go through the new onboarding listed on their site?

> Important EOL Notice: As of Thursday, Jan. 3, 2019, the weather.yahooapis.com and query.yahooapis.com for Yahoo Weather API will be retired. 
>   To continue using our free Yahoo Weather APIs, use https://weather-ydn-yql.media.yahoo.com/forecastrss. Contact yahoo-weather-ydn-api@oath.com for credentials to onboard to this free Yahoo Weather API service.

Comment: "They are retiring their weather API" — That's what the very first sentence of the question says!

Comment: "To continue using our free Yahoo Weather APIs, use https://weather-ydn-yql.media.yahoo.com/forecastrss." — That's the URL the OP said they were using!

Comment: "Did you go through the new onboarding listed on their site?" — The question says: Got whitelisted my app through email as instructed here, https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/